# Given a bunch of integer numbers, please output all combination of all possible numbers by using plus operation only

Tags: java, algorithm

Given a bunch of integer numbers, please output all combination of all possible numbers by using plus operation only.

For example,

```
[10, 20] => [10, 20, 30]
[1, 2, 3] => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[10, 20, 20, 50] => [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
```

Could someone help me with a method to do that in Java ?

I have made tries and I think it works, but looking for other solutions.

```
public int[] getCoins2(int[] coins) {
    Set<Integer> result = new TreeSet<>();

    for (int coin : coins) {
        result.addAll(result.stream().map(value -> value + coin).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
        result.add(coin);
    }

    return toInt(result);
}

public int[] toInt(Set<Integer> set) {
    int[] a = new int[set.size()];

    int i = 0;

    for (Integer val : set) {
        a[i++] = val;
    }

    return a;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    CoinCombination combination = new CoinCombination();
    int[] coins = {10, 20, 20, 50, 100};

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(combination.getCoins2(coins)));
}
```

Comment: OP, has your account been hacked or something? It appears you have been a member for 5 years, I think you know how SO works?

Comment: Hint: start with a bubble sort algorithm, but don't actually sort the list. Rather put the sum of elements into a hashset

Comment: What do you mean you "think it works"? Do you have unit tests?

Comment: I do not know how OP works. I have not posted any question for long time

Comment: I had unit test, but i cannot cover all the cases

Comment: Okay, then show the ones that fail, and the output you're getting... Also, stepping through with a debugger would help

Comment: It does not matter if the source array is sorted or not, it will not impact result

Comment: I do not have the one failed, I mean all my test cases passed from size one array to size 5 array

Comment: I specifically said not to sort the list, rather I implied to start with a nested for loop over the values

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184004/discussion-between-cricket-007-and-sendon1982).

Comment: “Looking for other solutions” is not a very good question

Comment: Related: [Return all possible sums that can be formed by using numbers in array JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34965270/return-all-possible-sums-that-can-be-formed-by-using-numbers-in-array-java). Search for more.

Comment: I’d go for a recursive method for generating the combinations and a `TreeSet` for storing the results for sorted output.

Comment: When you say all possible sums, do you mean subsequence sums as well?

Comment: If you have 5 numbers in your array, then each number can be included, or not included in the sum.  That maps neatly to 5 binary bits.  Generate all the binary numbers from b00000 to b11111.  Calculate the sums of all numbers which are flagged with a 1.  Remove duplicate results and you have solved the problem.

Comment: @vivek_23 yes, you can use only one number or two or all to sum up to have a new result.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks, i checked it, but i found out it is hard to understand recursion version for me  :(

Comment: Assuming your iterative code is doing the job, you don’t need to bother. Recursion is hard to understand at first, a great tool once you master it (at long last).

Comment: OK, i will keep to study more about recurssion

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in your problem statement:

> please output all combination of all possible numbers by using plus
>   operation only.

- The time complexity of the solution is going to remain exponential, that is, **O(2<sup>N</sup>-1)**, since we have to try every subsequence of the array.
- Since you are using a **TreeSet**, the complexity of `add` will add a overhead of log(n) and addAll() would add a complexity of `O(m log (n))` in the worst case, where `m` and `n` are the number of elements in each tree. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3390486/4964822).
- Technically speaking, this would add up the O(m log(n)) complexity at each step making it O(2<sup>N</sup> - 1) * O(m log(n)).
- I suggest you to better use a **HashSet** where `add()` and `contains()` would give you a O(1) performance on average(could go up to O(n) if there are collisions but is usually not the case).
- This way, complexity remains O(2<sup>N</sup>-1) with an `additional`(not multiplicative) overhead of sort at the end(if you `wish` to have it sorted) which would be `O(m log m)` where `m` ~ 2<sup>N</sup> - 1. You can compare run time of both approaches too.

**Code:**

```
import java.util.*;
public class CoinCombination {
        public List<Integer> getCoinSums(int[] coins) {
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
        List<Integer> sums = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int coin : coins) {
            int size = sums.size(); 
            for(int j=0;j<size;++j){
                int new_sum = sums.get(j) + coin;
                if(!set.contains(new_sum)){
                    sums.add(new_sum);   
                    set.add(new_sum);
                }
            }
            if(!set.contains(coin)){
                sums.add(coin);
                set.add(coin);
            }
        }

        Collections.sort(sums);
        return sums;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CoinCombination combination = new CoinCombination();
        int[][] coins = {
            {10,20},
            {1,2,3},
            {10, 20, 20, 50},
            {10, 20, 20, 50, 100}
        };
        for(int[] each_set_of_coins : coins){
            System.out.println(combination.getCoinSums(each_set_of_coins).toString());
        }        
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[10, 20, 30]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180, 190, 200]
```

Comment: @sendon1982 Glad to help :)